# Forward website traffic to a different firewalled server using SSH

Tags: ssh

I'm trying to forward website traffic to a secondary server (as a temp workaround) using SSH.

ServerA for example can be accessed with serverA.example.com:8080

ServerB can't be accessed from outside, but running a wget localhost:8888 on ServerB returns the website I want to display on serverA.example.com:8080

Both serverA and serverB can be SSH'ed into.

I'm guessing for this scenario, Remote Forwarding is needed ...

So from ServerA, I run the following:

```
ssh -R8080:localhost:8888 jan@serverB.example.com
```

or

```
ssh -R8888:localhost:8080 jan@serverB.example.com
```

In both cases if I go to serverA.example.com:8080, I get a "This webpage is not available"

In short, I need to be able to point my browser to serverA:8080 which should forward it to serverB:8888 via SSH as SSH is the only open port on serverB.

Any idea how I can get this setup working?

Comment: Not really clear what you are asking for. You want to access webserverA from serverB using 8888 port ?

Comment: I want to point my browser to serverA.example.com and serve a website running on serverB.example.com. serverB.example.com is firewalled, the only open port from the outside is port 22, which means I can only SSH into the box. serverB.example.com is serving a page on port 8888. So I need to forward my request from serverA:8080 via serverB:22 to serverB:8888

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use Remote port forwarding `-R` but Local port forwarding `-L`. As this on serverA :

```
ssh -L8080:localhost:8888 jan@serverB.example.com
```

This will redirect local port 8080 from serverA to port 8888 on serverB through the ssh connection to serverB.

Be sure that nothing is running on local port 8080 on serverA before launching your command.

Comment: I'm running it on ServerA, getting "Last login: Thu Jul  3 15:44:19 2014 from" and "/usr/bin/xmodmap:  unable to open display ''", and then it's SSHed into ServerB. Pointing the browser to serverA:8080 just says webpage not available, on ServerB, localhost:8888 displays the correct test page. Going to try on another setup ...

Comment: Can you add `-vv` to your ssh command on serverA. So we can check if there is any binding error.

Comment: Do you still have troubles ?

Comment: Haven't had time to test again, will try with -vv later this week.